# What time do bond traders come into office in morning in New York?

Tags: trading, futures

When I worked on bond desk in we need to be there 8am est.  Is this typical ? Seems late to me as some markets open 8am like the Canada bond futures.  Treasuries futures open 820am.

I work at hedge now and 7am we need to be in office.

This relates to prop strategy I'm working on that is trying to look at prices traders first see when coming into office.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about quantitative finance within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: I should be clearer.  This relates to strategy I'm working on but do not wish to divulge quant details due to proprietary considerations.

Comment: You already know the answer: it starts at 820 and you need to be in the office about 8.

Comment: Well old job I had to be in at 8am but now 7am.  So I'm wondering when most bond traders get into office.  I wonder if 7 or 8 is most common.